# Xcode - crash opening camara on ipad

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

My iphone app use camara to take photo.
Installing the app on ipad, the access to camara make the app crash.
Someone knows if any difference exists on use the picker controller between iphone and ipad?

Tx in advance

---EDIT---

he codeo that thaht call the camara I using is:

```
- (void) showCamera{
    UIImagePickerController * imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing =YES;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Yes difference is there.. so , first post your code that you written to open the camera the we will guide you what you are doing wrong.